# SQL Entry primary key duplicate in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Something went wrong on my MySQL database in the `product_variant` table and I basically need to restore the information.

I need to insert this, however it keeps coming up with this error:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY

Does anyone know what I can do?

[Product_variant Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuKnZ.png)

```
INSERT INTO `product_variant` (`Auto_ID`, `Product_ID`, `Product_Code`, `Product_Barcode`, `Info_1`, `Info_2`, `Info_3`, `Info_4`, `Info_5`, `Info_6`, `Price_Ex_VAT`, `Price_Inc_VAT`, `Price_Sale`, `Price_Final`, `Stock`, `Presale`, `Sold_Count`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'BD225', '5060246900125', '2', '7', '2.2m', '3.7m', '6.5kg', '', 49.17, 59.00, NULL, 59.00, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(2, '1', 'BD230', '5060246900187', '2', '9', '2.7m', '4.7m', '8kg', '', 57.49, 68.99, NULL, 68.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(3, '1', 'BD235', '5060246900194', '2', '11', '3.3m', '5.9m', '11kg', '', 71.66, 85.99, NULL, 85.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(4, '1', 'BD240', '5060246900200', '2', '13', '3.8m', '6.9m', '14.5kg', '', 89.16, 106.99, NULL, 106.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(5, '1', 'BD245', '5060246900217', '2', '15', '4.4m', '8.1m', '16kg', '', 99.99, 119.99, NULL, 119.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(6, '1', 'BD325', '5060246900224', '3', '7', '2.2m', '5.2m', '8.5kg', '', 68.74, 82.49, NULL, 82.49, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(7, '1', 'BD330', '5060246900231', '3', '9', '2.7m', '6.7m', '14.5kg', '', 95.83, 114.99, NULL, 114.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(8, '1', 'BD335', '5060246900248', '3', '11', '3.3m', '8.5m', '19kg', '', 114.16, 136.99, NULL, 136.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(17, '3', '44025', '5010845420258', '2', '9', '2.59m', '4.48m', '8.4kg', '', 59.16, 70.99, NULL, 70.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(18, '3', '44028', '5010845420289', '2', '10', '2.86m', '5.02m', '9.3kg', '', 72.49, 86.99, NULL, 86.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(19, '3', '44035', '5010845420357', '2', '12', '3.4m', '6.1m', '11.5kg', '', 87.49, 104.99, NULL, 104.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(20, '3', '44040', '5010845420401', '2', '14', '3.94m', '7.10m', '13.9kg', '', 97.49, 116.99, NULL, 116.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(21, '3', '44042', '5010845420425', '2', '15', '4.2m', '7.71m', '17kg', '', 112.49, 134.99, NULL, 134.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(22, '3', '44422', '5010845444223', '3', '8', '2.21m', '5.53m', '10kg', '', 92.49, 110.99, NULL, 110.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(23, '3', '44003', '5010845440034', '3', '9', '2.57m', '6.35m', '12.9kg', '', 98.33, 117.99, NULL, 117.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(24, '3', '44428', '5010845444285', '3', '10', '2.83m', '7.19m', '15kg', '', 114.99, 137.99, NULL, 137.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(25, '4', '570002', '', '2', '9', '2.79m', '4.42m', '8.24kg', '', 74.99, 89.99, NULL, 89.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(26, '4', '570003', '', '2', '11', '3.38m', '5.98m', '10.45kg', '', 96.66, 115.99, NULL, 115.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(27, '4', '570004', '', '2', '13', '3.95m', '7.14m', '13.1kg', '', 104.99, 125.99, NULL, 125.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(28, '4', '570005', '', '2', '15', '4.53m', '8.3m', '18.7kg', '', 121.66, 145.99, NULL, 145.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(29, '4', '570011', '', '3', '7', '2.21m', '5.11m', '10.4kg', '', 92.49, 110.99, NULL, 110.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(30, '4', '570012', '', '3', '9', '2.79m', '6.85m', '14.67kg', '', 109.16, 130.99, NULL, 130.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(31, '4', '570013', '', '3', '11', '3.37m', '8.59m', '24.7kg', '', 144.99, 173.99, NULL, 173.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(32, '5', 'ELT225', '', '2', '8', '2.4m', '3.82m', '8kg', '', 59.99, 85.99, 71.99, 71.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(33, '5', 'ELT230', '', '2', '10', '2.95m', '4.88m', '10.5kg', '', 69.16, 103.99, 82.99, 82.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(34, '5', 'ELT235', '', '2', '12', '3.42m', '5.94m', '14kg', '', 87.46, 118.99, 104.95, 104.95, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(35, '5', 'ELT240', '', '2', '14', '4.04m', '7.03m', '16kg', '', 99.16, 134.99, 118.99, 118.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(36, '5', 'ELT245', '', '2', '15', '4.42m', '7.81m', '20.5kg', '', 113.33, 149.99, 135.99, 135.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(37, '5', 'ELT250', '', '2', '17', '4.92m', '8.83m', '23.5kg', '', 124.99, 168.99, 149.99, 149.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(38, '5', 'ELT255', '', '2', '19', '5.42m', '9.9m', '29kg', '', 135.83, 183.99, 162.99, 162.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(39, '5', 'ELT325', '', '3', '8', '2.42m', '5.22m', '16.5kg', '', 94.16, 119.99, 112.99, 112.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(40, '5', 'ELT330', '', '3', '10', '2.92m', '6.85m', '18.5kg', '', 109.58, 133.99, 131.49, 131.49, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1),
(41, '5', 'ELT335', '', '3', '12', '3.42m', '8.46m', '25.5kg', '', 135.83, 163.99, 162.99, 162.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(42, '5', 'ELT340', '', '3', '14', '4.04m', '10.2m', '28.5kg', '', 155.41, 190.99, 186.49, 186.49, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(54, '7', '570111', '', '2', '8', '2.5m', '3.95m', '8.21kg', '', 83.33, 99.99, NULL, 99.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(55, '7', '570112', '', '2', '10', '3.08m', '5.11m', '9.97kg', '', 92.49, 110.99, NULL, 110.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(56, '7', '570113', '', '2', '12', '3.42m', '5.94m', '14kg', '', 96.66, 115.99, NULL, 115.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(57, '7', '570114', '', '2', '14', '4.24m', '7.43m', '17.44kg', '', 124.99, 149.99, NULL, 149.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(58, '7', '570115', '', '2', '16', '4.82m', '8.59m', '21.84kg', '', 138.33, 165.99, NULL, 165.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(59, '7', '570116', '', '2', '18', '5.4m', '9.75m', '28.73kg', '', 166.66, 199.99, NULL, 199.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(60, '7', '570121', '', '3', '8', '2.5m', '5.57m', '13.76kg', '', 113.33, 135.99, NULL, 135.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(61, '7', '570122', '', '3', '10', '3.08m', '7.43m', '20.99kg', '', 138.33, 165.99, NULL, 165.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(62, '7', '570123', '', '3', '12', '3.66m', '9.17m', '25.82kg', '', 179.99, 215.99, NULL, 215.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(63, '7', '570124', '', '3', '14', '4.24m', '10.62m', '34.81kg', '', 204.99, 245.99, NULL, 245.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(64, '8', '72418', '5010845724189', '2', '6', '1.84m', '2.68m', '-', '7.6kg', 94.16, 112.99, NULL, 112.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(65, '8', '72424', '5010845724240', '2', '8', '2.4m', '3.8m', '-', '10.2kg', 103.33, 123.99, NULL, 123.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(66, '8', '72429', '5010845724295', '2', '10', '2.96m', '4.92m', '-', '13kg', 110.83, 132.99, NULL, 132.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(67, '8', '72435', '5010845724356', '2', '12', '3.52m', '6.04m', '-', '17.3kg', 129.16, 154.99, NULL, 154.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(68, '8', '72441', '5010845724417', '2', '14', '4.08m', '7.16m', '-', '21.6kg', 141.66, 169.99, NULL, 169.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(69, '8', '72518', '5010845725186', '3', '6', '1.84m', '3.78m', '2.92m', '11.6kg', 115.83, 138.99, NULL, 138.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(70, '8', '72524', '5010845725247', '3', '8', '2.4m', '5.18m', '3.76m', '15.1kg', 137.49, 164.99, NULL, 164.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(71, '8', '72529', '5010845725292', '3', '10', '2.96m', '6.86m', '4.88m', '19.4kg', 159.16, 190.99, NULL, 190.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(72, '8', '72535', '5010845725353', '3', '12', '3.52m', '8.54m', '5.72m', '25.6kg', 193.33, 231.99, NULL, 231.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(73, '8', '72541', '5010845725415', '3', '14', '4.08m', '10.22m', '6.56m', '32.1kg', 227.49, 272.99, NULL, 272.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(74, '9', 'IND225', '', '2', '9', '2.5m', '4.25m', '11kg', '', 104.99, 125.99, NULL, 125.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(75, '9', 'IND230', '', '2', '11', '3m', '5.25m', '13kg', '', 113.33, 135.99, NULL, 135.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(76, '9', 'IND235', '', '2', '13', '3.5m', '6.25m', '17kg', '', 133.33, 159.99, NULL, 159.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(77, '9', 'IND240', '', '2', '15', '4m', '7.25m', '20kg', '', 149.99, 179.99, NULL, 179.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(78, '9', 'IND245', '', '2', '17', '4.5m', '8.25m', '26kg', '', 166.66, 199.99, NULL, 199.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(79, '9', 'IND250', '', '2', '19', '5m', '9.25m', '29kg', '', 182.49, 218.99, NULL, 218.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(81, '9', 'IND325', '', '3', '9', '2.5m', '6m', '20kg', '', 130.83, 156.99, NULL, 156.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(82, '9', 'IND330', '', '2', '11', '3m', '7.5m', '28kg', '', 182.49, 218.99, NULL, 218.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(83, '9', 'IND335', '', '3', '13', '3.5m', '9m', '32kg', '', 199.99, 239.99, NULL, 239.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(84, '9', 'IND340', '', '3', '15', '4m', '10m', '39kg', '', 260.83, 312.99, NULL, 312.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(96, '11', 'ROPE235', '', '2', '13', '3.37m', '5.95m', '20kg', '', 256.66, 307.99, NULL, 307.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(97, '11', 'ROPE240', '', '2', '15', '3.94m', '7.21m', '23.1kg', '', 279.16, 334.99, NULL, 334.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(98, '11', 'ROPE245', '', '2', '17', '4.44m', '8.21m', '26.8kg', '', 299.16, 358.99, NULL, 358.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(99, '11', 'ROPE250', '', '2', '19', '4.94m', '8.96m', '29.9kg', '', 324.99, 389.99, NULL, 389.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(100, '11', 'ROPE255', '', '2', '21', '5.44m', '9.96m', '37.2kg', '', 382.49, 458.99, NULL, 458.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(101, '11', 'ROPE260', '', '2', '23', '5.94m', '10.71m', '45.4kg', '', 407.49, 488.99, NULL, 488.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(102, '11', 'ROPE270', '', '2', '27', '6.94m', '12.71m', '50.4kg', '', 465.83, 558.99, NULL, 558.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(103, '11', 'ROPE340', '', '3', '15', '3.94m', '10.47m', '43.5kg', '', 465.83, 558.99, NULL, 558.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(104, '11', 'ROPE345', '', '3', '17', '4.44m', '11.97m', '52.6kg', '', 545.83, 654.99, NULL, 654.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(105, '11', 'ROPE350', '', '3', '19', '4.94m', '12.97m', '58.5kg', '', 576.66, 691.99, NULL, 691.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(106, '11', 'ROPE355', '', '3', '21', '5.44m', '13.97m', '64.9kg', '', 604.16, 724.99, NULL, 724.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(107, '11', 'ROPE360', '', '3', '23', '5.94m', '15.47m', '71.2kg', '', 665.83, 798.99, NULL, 798.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(118, '13', 'TRL130', '', '1', '11', '2.95', '8.5kg', '', '', 87.49, 111.99, 104.99, 104.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(119, '13', 'TRL135', '', '1', '13', '3.45m', '10kg', '', '', 91.66, 117.99, 109.99, 109.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(120, '13', 'TRL140', '', '1', '15', '3.95m', '11kg', '', '', 95.83, 123.99, 114.99, 114.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1),
(121, '13', 'TRL145', '', '1', '17', '4.5m', '11.5kg', '', '', 104.16, 135.99, 124.99, 124.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(122, '13', 'TRL150', '', '1', '19', '4.97m', '12kg', '', '', 108.33, 141.99, 129.99, 129.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(123, '13', 'TRL155', '', '1', '21', '5.46m', '13.5kg', '', '', 115.83, 152.99, 138.99, 138.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(124, '14', 'TRL230', '', '2', '11 + 9', '2.94m', '4.64m', '14kg', '', 115.83, 143.99, 138.99, 138.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(125, '14', 'TRL235', '', '2', '13 + 11', '3.44m', '5.64m', '16kg', '', 129.16, 159.99, 154.99, 154.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(126, '14', 'TRL240', '', '2', '15 + 13', '3.94m', '6.64m', '18kg', '', 139.16, 171.99, 166.99, 166.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(127, '14', 'TRL245', '', '2', '17 + 15', '4.3m', '7.67m', '20kg', '', 149.99, 183.99, 179.99, 179.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(128, '15', '42755', '5010845427554', '1', '16', '2.88m', '5.27m', '13.5kg', '', 149.99, 179.99, NULL, 179.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(129, '16', '27016', '5010845270167', '2', '1.56m', '2.74m', '6.3kg', '', '', 54.99, 65.99, NULL, 65.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(130, '17', 'SPL', '0610395807797', '1.6m', '2.7m', '0.95m', '1.47m', '15.5kg', '', 66.66, 79.99, NULL, 79.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1),
(131, '18', '75013', '5010845750133', '2', '1.56m', '2.74m', '7.4kg', '', '', 73.33, 87.99, NULL, 87.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(132, '19', 'CL6', '', '3', '6', '1.72m', '2.43m', '3.4m', '9.15kg', 72.49, 86.99, NULL, 86.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(133, '19', 'CL7', '', '3', '7', '1.99m', '2.95m', '4.24m', '10.55kg', 84.99, 101.99, NULL, 101.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(134, '19', 'CL8', '', '3', '8', '2.27m', '3.48m', '5.07m', '12.6kg', 90.83, 108.99, NULL, 108.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(135, '19', 'CL9', '', '3', '9', '2.56m', '4m', '5.92m', '15.1kg', 112.49, 134.99, NULL, 134.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(136, '19', 'CL10', '', '3', '10', '2.84m', '4.25m', '6.48m', '15.55kg', 119.16, 142.99, NULL, 142.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(137, '19', 'CL11', '', '3', '11', '3.12m', '4.77m', '7.32m', '21.3kg', 147.49, 176.99, NULL, 176.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(141, '21', '1021-701', '', '7', '2.92m', '4.24m', '12kg', '', '', 91.66, 109.99, NULL, 109.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(142, '21', '1027-701', '', '9', '3.61m', '5.12m', '14.5kg', '', '', 99.99, 119.99, NULL, 119.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(143, '21', '1033-701', '', '11', '4.3m', '5.72m', '17.5kg', '', '', 120.83, 144.99, NULL, 144.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(144, '22', '75004', '5010845750041', '3', '1.56m', '3.91m', '2.74m', '12.1kg', '', 106.66, 127.99, NULL, 127.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(145, '23', '75005', '5010845750058', '1.56m', '2.74m', '1.2m', '1.2m x 0.32m', '12.9kg', '', 119.99, 143.99, NULL, 143.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(146, '24', '9306-501', '4007126930613', '3', '2x6 + 1x5', '1.92m', '3.7m', '2.85m', '15.4kg', 133.33, 159.99, NULL, 159.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(147, '24', '9309-501', '4007126930927', '3', '2x9 + 1x8', '2.74m', '5.6m', '4.18m', '20.7kg', 158.33, 189.99, NULL, 189.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(148, '24', '9312-501', '4007126931221', '3', '3x12', '3.57m', '8.15m', '5.53m', '30.5kg', 199.99, 239.99, NULL, 239.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(149, '25', '40227', '', '3 x 6', '1.9m', '4.1m', '3m', '13.8kg', '', 183.33, 219.99, NULL, 219.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(150, '25', '40228', '', '3 x 8', '2.4m', '5.8m', '4.1m', '17.5kg', '', 215.83, 258.99, NULL, 258.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(151, '25', '40229', '', '3 x 10', '3m', '6.9m', '4.96m', '23.8kg', '', 249.99, 299.99, NULL, 299.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(152, '25', '40230', '', '3 x 12', '3.6m', '8.6m', '6.1m', '28.8kg', '', 299.99, 359.99, NULL, 359.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(153, '25', '41231', '', '3 x 14', '4.1m', '9.7m', '6.9m', '36.4kg', '', 374.99, 449.99, NULL, 449.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(154, '26', '41521', '', '3 x 8', '2.45m', '5.8m', '4.1m', '18.5kg', '', 283.33, 339.99, NULL, 339.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(155, '26', '41522', '', '3 x 10', '3.01m', '6.9m', '4.96m', '24.3kg', '', 346.66, 415.99, NULL, 415.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(156, '26', '41523', '', '3 x 12', '3.57m', '8.6m', '6.1m', '30.1kg', '', 374.99, 449.99, NULL, 449.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(157, '26', '41524', '', '3 x 14', '4.14m', '9.7m', '6.95m', '38.4kg', '', 441.66, 529.99, NULL, 529.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(158, '27', 'TEL26-6', '0610395807759', '9', '0.73m', '2.6m', '8kg', '', '', 62.49, 74.99, NULL, 74.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(159, '27', 'TEL32-6', '0610395807766', '11', '0.8m', '3.2m', '9kg', '', '', 74.99, 89.99, NULL, 89.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(160, '27', 'TEL38-6', '0610395807773', '13', '0.87m', '3.8m', '11.5kg', '', '', 83.33, 99.99, NULL, 99.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1),
(161, '28', 'ATLS4X3', '0610395807834', '4', '3', '1.49m', '3.03m', '10.5kg', '', 69.16, 82.99, NULL, 82.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(162, '28', 'ATLS4X4', '0610395807841', '4', '4', '2.03m', '4.19m', '12.8kg', '', 74.99, 89.99, NULL, 89.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(163, '29', '87302', '', '2.35m - 2.45m', '0.52m x 0.6m', '12.5kg', '', '', '', 166.66, 199.99, NULL, 199.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(164, '29', '87301', '', '2.65m - 2.93m', '0.52m x 0.92m - 1.1m', '15.3kg', '', '', '', 208.33, 249.99, NULL, 249.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(165, '30', 'MPL37', '0610395807803', '4', '1m', '1.8m', '3.7m', '1m', '15kg', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1),
(167, '32', 'GFMPL4X3', '', '4', '0.95m', '1.75m', '3.56m', '0.95m', '16.5kg', 95.83, 114.99, NULL, 114.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(168, '33', '75053', '5010845750539', '4', '3', '0.92m - 1.46m', '1.78m - 2.88m', '13.5kg', '', 95.83, 114.99, NULL, 114.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(169, '33', '75054', '5010845750546', '4', '4', '1.17m - 1.98m', '2.37m - 3.98m', '17kg', '', 108.33, 129.99, NULL, 129.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(171, '34', 'TLS4X4', '', '4', '4', '1.3m - 2.16m', '2.66m - 4.42m', '13.7kg', '', 118.33, 141.99, NULL, 141.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(175, '37', 'ADSL3', '0610395807810', '2 x 3', '0.59m', '3kg', '', '', '', 27.49, 32.99, NULL, 32.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(176, '37', 'ADSL4', '0610395807827', '2 x 4', '0.79m', '4kg', '', '', '', 31.66, 37.99, NULL, 37.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(177, '38', '13012', '5010845130126', '2', '0.35m', '2kg', '', '', '', 30.83, 36.99, NULL, 36.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(178, '38', '13013', '5010845130133', '3', '0.58m', '2.5kg', '', '', '', 33.33, 39.99, NULL, 39.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(179, '38', '13014', '5010845130140', '4', '0.8m', '3kg', '', '', '', 34.99, 41.99, NULL, 41.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(180, '38', '13015', '5010845130157', '5', '1.03m', '3.6kg', '', '', '', 39.16, 46.99, NULL, 46.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(181, '38', '13016', '', '6', '1.25m', '4.3kg', '', '', '', 47.49, 56.99, NULL, 56.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(182, '38', '13017', '5010845130171', '7', '1.48m', '4.8kg', '', '', '', 54.99, 65.99, NULL, 65.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(183, '38', '13018', '5010845130188', '8', '1.75m', '7.4kg', '', '', '', 64.16, 76.99, NULL, 76.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(184, '39', '8140-301', '4007126007759', '3', '1.25m', '0.62m', '3.3kg', '', '', 29.16, 34.99, NULL, 34.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(185, '39', '8140-401', '4007126007766', '4', '1.46m', '0.84m', '3.9kg', '', '', 32.49, 38.99, NULL, 38.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(186, '39', '8140-501', '4007126007773', '5', '1.68m', '1.06m', '4.6kg', '', '', 39.99, 47.99, NULL, 47.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(187, '39', '8140-601', '4007126007780', '6', '1.9m', '1.28m', '5.5kg', '', '', 44.16, 52.99, NULL, 52.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(188, '39', '8140-701', '4007126007797', '7', '2.12m', '1.5m', '6.3kg', '', '', 49.99, 59.99, NULL, 59.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(189, '39', '8140-801', '4007126007803', '8', '2.33m', '1.72m', '7.3kg', '', '', 57.49, 68.99, NULL, 68.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(190, '40', '60003', '', '3', '0.58m', '2.9kg', '', '', '', 34.16, 40.99, NULL, 40.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(191, '40', '60004', '', '4', '0.8m', '3.4kg', '', '', '', 38.33, 45.99, NULL, 45.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(192, '40', '60005', '', '5', '1.03m', '3.9kg', '', '', '', 45.83, 54.99, NULL, 54.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(193, '40', '60006', '', '6', '1.25m', '4.6kg', '', '', '', 50.83, 60.99, NULL, 60.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(194, '40', '60007', '', '7', '1.48m', '6kg', '', '', '', 58.33, 69.99, NULL, 69.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(195, '40', '60008', '', '8', '1.75m', '7.2kg', '', '', '', 66.66, 79.99, NULL, 79.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(196, '41', '8030-301', '4007126007346', '3', '1.25m', '0.62m', '4kg', '', '', 43.33, 51.99, NULL, 51.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(197, '41', '8030-401', '4007126007353', '4', '1.46m', '0.84m', '4.8kg', '', '', 49.99, 59.99, NULL, 59.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(198, '41', '8030-501', '4007126007360', '5', '1.68m', '1.06m', '5.8kg', '', '', 55.83, 66.99, NULL, 66.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(199, '41', '8030-601', '4007126007377', '6', '1.9m', '1.28m', '6.6kg', '', '', 62.49, 74.99, NULL, 74.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(200, '42', '70502', '5010845705027', '2', '1.1m', '0.35m', '4.25kg', '', '', 51.66, 61.99, NULL, 61.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(201, '42', '70503', '5010845705034', '3', '1.33m', '0.58m', '5kg', '', '', 55.83, 66.99, NULL, 66.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(202, '42', '70504', '5010845705041', '4', '1.55m', '0.8m', '5.75kg', '', '', 59.16, 70.99, NULL, 70.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(203, '42', '70505', '5010845705058', '5', '1.77m', '1.03m', '4.5kg', '', '', 65.83, 78.99, NULL, 78.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(204, '42', '70506', '5010845705065', '6', '2m', '1.25m', '7.5kg', '', '', 76.66, 91.99, NULL, 91.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(205, '42', '70507', '5010845705072', '7', '2.22m', '1.48m', '9kg', '', '', 93.33, 111.99, NULL, 111.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(206, '42', '70508', '5010845705089', '8', '2.53m', '1.79m', '9.7kg', '', '', 127.49, 152.99, NULL, 152.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(207, '43', '8655-001', '4007126865502', '2 x 5', '1.2m', '1.1m', '5kg', '', '', 58.33, 69.99, NULL, 69.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(208, '43', '8657-001', '4007126865700', '2 x 7', '1.67m', '1.54m', '7.2kg', '', '', 66.66, 79.99, NULL, 79.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(209, '44', '8010-301', '4007126007209', '3', '1.25m', '0.62m', '5kg', '', '', 62.49, 74.99, NULL, 74.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(210, '44', '8010-401', '4007126007216', '4', '1.46m', '0.84m', '6kg', '', '', 70.83, 84.99, NULL, 84.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(211, '44', '8010-501', '4007126007223', '5', '1.68m', '1.06m', '7kg', '', '', 79.16, 94.99, NULL, 94.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(212, '44', '8010-601', '4007126007247', '6', '1.9m', '1.28m', '8.5kg', '', '', 91.66, 109.99, NULL, 109.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(213, '88', 'ESS3', '', '3', '0.66m', '0.58m', '-', '2.4kg', '', 37.49, 53.99, 44.99, 44.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(214, '88', 'ESS4', '', '4', '0.89m', '0.81m', '-', '2.5kg', '', 41.66, 59.99, 49.99, 49.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(215, '88', 'ESS5', '', '5', '1.14m', '1.03m', '-', '3.4kg', '', 48.33, 69.99, 57.99, 57.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(216, '88', 'ESS6', '', '6', '1.38m', '1.26m', '-', '4.5kg', '', 52.49, 75.99, 62.99, 62.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(217, '88', 'ESS7', '', '7', '1.62m', '1.48m', '-', '5.1kg', '', 54.99, 78.99, 65.99, 65.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(218, '88', 'ESS8', '', '8', '1.86m', '1.7m', '-', '6kg', '', 56.66, 81.99, 67.99, 67.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(219, '88', 'ESS10', '', '10', '2.34m', '2.17m', '-', '6.6kg', '', 67.49, 96.99, 80.99, 80.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(220, '88', 'ESS12', '', '12', '2.82m', '2.57m', '-', '7.3kg', '', 75.83, 108.99, 90.99, 90.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(221, '88', 'ESP3', '', '3', '1.35m', '1.24m', '0.59m', '4.2kg', '', 49.16, 70.99, 58.99, 58.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(222, '88', 'ESP4', '', '4', '1.59m', '1.46m', '0.81m', '4.5kg', '', 53.33, 76.99, 63.99, 63.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(223, '88', 'ESP5', '', '5', '1.83m', '1.68m', '1.03m', '5.4kg', '', 56.66, 81.99, 67.99, 67.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(224, '88', 'ESP6', '', '6', '2.07m', '1.91m', '1.26m', '6kg', '', 63.33, 90.99, 75.99, 75.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(225, '88', 'ESP7', '', '7', '2.31m', '2.13m', '1.48m', '6.6kg', '', 69.16, 99.99, 82.99, 82.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(226, '88', 'ESP8', '', '8', '2.55m', '2.31m', '1.67m', '7.25kg', '', 73.33, 105.99, 87.99, 87.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(227, '88', 'ESP10', '', '10', '3.01m', '2.74m', '2.12m', '8.8kg', '', 85.83, 123.99, 102.99, 102.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(228, '88', 'ESP12', '', '12', '3.52m', '3.2m', '2.6m', '9.5kg', '', 92.49, 132.99, 110.99, 110.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(247, '90', 'SP6', '', '6', '1.95m', '1.46m', '9.5kg', '', '', 143.33, 171.99, NULL, 171.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(248, '90', 'SP8', '', '8', '2.44m', '1.95m', '12.3kg', '', '', 160.83, 192.99, NULL, 192.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(249, '90', 'SP10', '', '10', '3.26m', '2.44m', '15kg', '', '', 197.49, 236.99, NULL, 236.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(250, '90', 'SP12', '', '12', '3.78m', '2.93m', '17.7kg', '', '', 220.83, 264.99, NULL, 264.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(251, '90', 'SP14', '', '14', '4.3m', '3.42m', '20.9kg', '', '', 245.83, 294.99, NULL, 294.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(252, '90', 'SP16', '', '16', '4.6m', '4.10m', '24.5kg', '', '', 256.66, 307.99, NULL, 307.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(253, '45', 'GFBB3', '', '3', '0.59m', '0.55m', '-', '2.7kg', '', 49.99, 59.99, NULL, 59.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(254, '45', 'GFBB4', '', '4', '0.85m', '0.77m', '-', '3.8kg', '', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(255, '45', 'GFBB5', '5060246900019', '5', '1.1m', '0.99m', '-', '4.9kg', '', 62.49, 74.99, NULL, 74.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(256, '45', 'GFBB6', '', '6', '1.34m', '1.22m', '-', '5.8kg', '', 70.83, 84.99, NULL, 84.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(257, '45', 'GFBB7', '', '7', '1.58m', '1.44m', '-', '6.7kg', '', 74.99, 89.99, NULL, 89.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(258, '45', 'GFBB8', '', '8', '1.81m', '1.7m', '-', '7.6kg', '', 83.33, 99.99, NULL, 99.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(259, '45', 'GFBB10', '', '10', '2.29m', '2.11m', '-', '11.5kg', '', 112.49, 134.99, NULL, 134.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(260, '45', 'GFBB12', '', '12', '2.77m', '2.54m', '-', '12.5kg', '', 124.99, 149.99, NULL, 149.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(261, '45', 'GFBP3', '', '3', '1.33m', '1.23m', '0.59m', '5.8kg', '', 70.83, 84.99, NULL, 84.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(262, '45', 'GFBP4', '', '4', '1.56m', '1.44m', '0.82m', '6.7kg', '', 74.99, 89.99, NULL, 89.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(263, '45', 'GFBP5', '', '5', '1.8m', '1.67m', '1.04m', '7.8kg', '', 83.33, 99.99, NULL, 99.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(264, '45', 'GFBP6', '5060246900835', '6', '2.04m', '1.89m', '1.26m', '8.8kg', '', 91.66, 109.99, NULL, 109.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(265, '45', 'GFBP7', '', '7', '2.27m', '2.1m', '1.48m', '9.6kg', '', 99.99, 119.99, NULL, 119.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(266, '45', 'GFBP8', '5060246900828', '8', '2.51m', '2.31m', '1.69m', '10.7kg', '', 104.16, 124.99, NULL, 124.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(267, '45', 'GFBP10', '5060246900811', '10', '3m', '2.73m', '2.11m', '13.6kg', '', 133.33, 159.99, NULL, 159.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(268, '45', 'GFBP12', '5060246900118', '12', '3.47m', '3.17m', '2.56m', '15.5kg', '', 145.83, 174.99, NULL, 174.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(281, '48', 'GFCL6', '', '3 x 6', '1.68m', '2.39m', '3.28m', '9.15kg', '', 116.66, 139.99, NULL, 139.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(282, '48', 'GFCL7', '', '3 x 7', '1.96m', '2.92m', '4.12m', '10.4kg', '', 129.99, 155.99, NULL, 155.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(283, '49', 'LFD44AL', '', '2 x 2', '0.51m', '0.46m', '1.8kg', '', '', 24.99, 39.99, 29.99, 29.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 1),
(284, '50', '13712', '5010845137125', '2', '0.45m', '4.2kg', '', '', '', 25.83, 30.99, NULL, 30.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(285, '51', '4392-801', '', '2', '0.9m', '0.82m', '0.46m', '3.3kg', '', 29.16, 34.99, NULL, 34.99, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 0),
(286, '51', '4393-801', '', '3', '1.16m', '1.05m', '0.69m', '4.6kg', '', 41.66, 49.99, NULL, 49.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(287, '52', '22042', '5010845220421', '2', '0.47m', '5kg', '', '', '', 38.33, 45.99, NULL, 45.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(288, '52', '22043', '5010845220438', '3', '0.72m', '8kg', '', '', '', 47.49, 56.99, NULL, 56.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(289, '53', '4422-001', '', '2 x 2', '0.5m', '0.44m', '2.1kg', '', '', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(290, '53', '4423-001', '', '3 x 2', '0.73m', '0.66m', '3.2kg', '', '', 66.66, 79.99, NULL, 79.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(291, '54', 'LD3', '', '2 x 3', '0.73m', '7.5kg', '', '', '', 99.99, 119.99, NULL, 119.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(292, '54', 'LD4', '', '2 x 4', '0.98m', '9kg', '', '', '', 108.33, 129.99, NULL, 129.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(293, '54', 'LD5', '', '2 x 5', '1.22m', '11kg', '', '', '', 124.99, 149.99, NULL, 149.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(294, '55', 'L3', '', '3', '0.73m', '6.5kg', '', '', '', 108.33, 129.99, NULL, 129.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(295, '55', 'L4', '', '4', '0.98m', '8kg', '', '', '', 124.99, 149.99, NULL, 149.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(296, '55', 'L5', '', '5', '1.22m', '9kg', '', '', '', 141.66, 169.99, NULL, 169.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(297, '56', 'WS4', '', '4', '1m', '9.9kg', '', '', '', 118.33, 141.99, NULL, 141.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(298, '56', 'WS5', '', '5', '1.22m', '11.3kg', '', '', '', 120.83, 144.99, NULL, 144.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(299, '56', 'WS6', '', '4', '1.46m', '12.7kg', '', '', '', 133.33, 159.99, NULL, 159.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(300, '56', 'WS7', '', '5', '1.71m', '14.5kg', '', '', '', 141.66, 169.99, NULL, 169.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(301, '56', 'WS8', '', '8', '1.95m', '15.9kg', '', '', '', 158.33, 189.99, NULL, 189.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(302, '56', 'WS10', '', '10', '2.44m', '20kg', '', '', '', 199.99, 239.99, NULL, 239.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(303, '56', 'WS12', '', '12', '2.93m', '23.6kg', '', '', '', 224.99, 269.99, NULL, 269.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(304, '56', 'WS14', '', '14', '3.42m', '26.8kg', '', '', '', 249.99, 299.99, NULL, 299.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(313, '58', 'LEL2', '', '2', '2.67m', '1.25m', '457 x 560mm', '', '', 49.99, 59.99, NULL, 59.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(314, '58', 'LEL3', '5036149000019', '3', '3m', '1.05m', '432 x 508mm', '', '', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(315, '59', '302340', '', '2', '2.6m', '1.45m', '1.21m', '', '', 41.66, 49.99, NULL, 49.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(317, '61', '36000', '5010845360004', '2', '2.69m', '0.71m', '(W) 0.38m', '', '', 49.99, 59.99, NULL, 59.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(426, '102', 'FSPL', '0602401856059', '1m', '1.54 x 0.45 x 1.07m', '1.54 x 0.45 x 0.15m', '11.5kg', '', '', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0),
(427, '103', 'FSPL', '0602401856059', '', '', '', '', '', '', 54.16, 64.99, NULL, 64.99, 'TRUE', '', 0);
```

Comment: I done an export backup last month with the Localhost.sql but I only want to edit and change the product_variant table. All I want to do is use this statement to go back to old prices and product codes. @MaxZoom

Comment: It complains about the primary key - how's it defined in product_variant  table

Comment: @MaxZoom It is defined as what is shown above, and links to another table called products. All I want to do is restore the product_variant as the prices have all changed to the same £47.99. Any ideas?

Comment: @MaxZoom should I do update and not insert?

Comment: When you view the table structure the primary key is displayed. I am not sure from what is provided what the PK is.

Comment: @MaxZoom How do I do an update for all those products do you know? I need to update all of the data that is shown :(

Comment: You have to drop and create the table again to run this query. Make sure you have the table SQL code before drop.

Comment: @MaxZoom I have provided an Image if you look at the top under description.

Comment: From the image AUTO_ID is PK. I would do as stated above

Comment: How do I drop the product_variant table? and to create the table I add the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would need something along these lines

```
-- Drop the table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_variant;

-- Recreate the table
CREATE TABLE product_variant (
  Auto_ID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (Auto_ID)
); 

-- insert your data
INSERT INTO product_variant ...
```

Comment: I am so grateful for your help this worked a charm. I believe you just saved my job. Thank you so so much I really appreciate your help and quick response. Hope you have a good Christmas.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.

Comment: I suspect if the question was basically "how do I run this backup", then `TRUNCATE product_variant` or `DELETE FROM product_variant` would have been simpler, since it does not require the recreation of the table.

Comment: I believe he has already used `DELETE` and run into the identity column issue, based on the SQL error provided. But `TRUNCATE` seems to do the job as well (assuming no more restriction is present)